# Can I implement Dynamics CRM 4.0 crmsvcutil out and classNameFormat functionality in 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Using the [crmsvcutil against Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681563.aspx) you could both output multiple class files to a directory (`out` parameter) as well as add a prefix or suffix to generated class names (`classNameFormat` parameter).

Unfortunately this functionality appears to have been removed with the [CRM 2011 tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695820.aspx).

Erik Pool has written on [Filtering generated entities with CrmSvcUtil](http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/03/filtering-generated-entities-with.html), which might be the path we need to take to do the first, but I haven't found anything that could help replace `classNameFormat`.

Instead of going through the generated class file(s) and manually making this modification, is there any way to extend crmsvcutil to handle this during generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this without manually updating all of your generated files by creating an extension that implements the `INamingService` interface.  The particular methods you're interested in will be `GetNameForEntity` and `GetNameForEntitySet`.  For all others just delegate to the default implementation provided in the constructor.

The CRM 2011 SDK is a [good place to start](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24004) as there are some code samples demonstrating the extensibility.

Comment: Thanks Daz, I'll give that a go this morning.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I ended up just tweaking `GetNameForEntity`, as updating `GetNameForEntitySet` resulted in duplication of my prefix. Unfortunately it doesn't assist with my need to connect to two different organizations, but it was worth a try!